# Stopwatch in JavaScript when function start

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make a script that counts how long it took me to execute this function (in ms)

I want it to start when the page loads

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (window.location.pathname == '/checkout/confirm') {
        sleep(10).then(() => {
            var checkout = document.evaluate('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/z-grid[1]/z-grid-item[2]/button', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
            checkout.singleNodeValue.click();
            console.log("Checkout Complete in x ms");
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't understand the question perfectly, you can simply wrap any function between `const start_time = new Date();` and `const time_took = new Date() - start_time;`, to get the execution time. What exactly are you facing issue with?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with `Date.now()`. Just check the time before and after the function and substract the results.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (window.location.pathname == '/checkout/confirm') {
        let start_function = Date.now();
        sleep(10).then(() => {
            var checkout = document.evaluate('/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div/z-grid[1]/z-grid-item[2]/button', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
            checkout.singleNodeValue.click();
            let end_function = Date.now();
            console.log(`Checkout Complete in ${ end_function - start_function } ms`);
        })
    }
})
```